# Are the buttons below the moderator agreement able to be made translatable or not?

Tags: support, moderators, localization, moderator-agreement

I know that there is some complexity with translating the SE moderator agreement to other languages (languages of some non-English sites), but what about the buttons?

> [image]

Should the Accept and Decline buttons be available for translations or not? (In other words, are they also part of the moderator agreement?)

Comment: For context to others: the moderator agreement, as a legal document, is in English on all sites rather than translated on the international sites to ensure there are no conflicts of interpretation between a translation and the original. What this question is asking is if those "Accept" and "Decline" buttons are considered "part" of the agreement (and therefore not to be translated) or if they're not and can be translated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I spoke with legal counsel about this.  At this time, we don't want to translate those buttons. If the documents are in English, counsel believes that the buttons should be as well.